# Bash history clean spesific one command

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on this bash script I want to clean bash_history file . But not all

this command run  on terminal  "history"

```
history | grep 'history'  |  awk '{ print $1 }'
```

output:

```
9210
9230
9231
9232
9233
9234
9244......
```

I want delete "history" command in history

my bash_history

```
10251  2022-11-10 20:07:20: history | grep 'history'  |  awk '{ print $1 }' | sed -i '$1' \~/.bash_history
10253  2022-11-10 20:11:03: history 1 | awk '{print $1}'
...
...
...
```

But my bash script not run this script output empty:

```
lines=$(history | grep 'history'  |  awk '{ print $1 }')
for i in lines
do 
  history -d "$i";
done
```

Comment: The problem is that when you delete a line from history, the indexes of all the following lines decrease. You should delete them in reverse order.

Comment: @Flankes I'd suggest using `HISTIGNORE` parameter to avoid submitting a command to 
 BASH history instead of innovating wheels on identifying & removing the command.

Here is an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32461

And this is what I have used in my User's `.bashrc` file, `HISTIGNORE='cd *:history *'` to ignore `cd` & `history` commands with any argument and/or option used.